# getting error in <script src = "/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sockets, socket.io

i know this question has been asked many times buit i have spent 3 hours trying to figure it out but to no avail. i am getting error in       GET 
    http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js net::ERR_ABORTED
    and io is not defined. any help would be highly appreciated. i am typing extra coz my post requires more details ..........

```
 public/index.html

 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="styles.css" />

</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">

            <div class="form_div" id ="login">
            <p class="form_label">LOGIN FORM</p>
            <form method="post" action="">
            <p><input id ="user-name" type="text" placeholder="Enter user-name"></p>
            <p><input id = "pass-word" type="password" placeholder="**********"></p>
            <p><input id = "submit" type="submit" value="LOGIN"></p>
            </form>
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div class="form_div" id = "signup">
            <p class="form_label">SIGNUP FORM</p>
            <form method="post" action="">
            <p><input id ="signupusername" type="text" placeholder="Enter 
             Name"></p>
            <p><input id = "signuppass" type="password" 
             placeholder="**********"></p>
            <p><input id ="register" type="submit" value="SIGNUP"></p>
            </form>
            </div>

            </div>
            <script src = "index.js"></script>
            <script src = "/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

```
public/index.js

 var socket = io();

var loginDiv = document.getElementById('login');
var Username = document.getElementById('user-name');
var loginPassword = document.getElementById('pass-word');
var login = document.getElementById('submit');
var SignUpDiv = document.getElementById('signup');
var Signupuser = document.getElementById('signupusername');
var Signuppass = document.getElementById('signuppass');
var signup = document.getElementById('register');


login.onclick = function(){
    socket.emit('login-details',{
        username:Username.value,
        password:loginPassword.value
    });
}

signup.onclick = function(){
    socket.emit('signup-details',{
        newuser:Signupuser.value,
        newuserpassword:Signuppass.val
    });
}

socket.on('login-response',(data)=>{
    if(data.success){
        alert('login Successful');
    }
    else{
        alert('login Unsuccessful');
    }
});

socket.on('signup-response',(data)=>{
    if(data.success){
        alert('Signup Successful')
    }
    else{
        alert('Signup-Successful')
    }
});









server/server.js


var express = require('express');

var path = require('path');

var http = require('http'); 

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

const socketIO = require('socket.io');



var app = express();

 var server = http.createServer(app);

const port = process.env.PORT ||3000;

var io = socketIO(server);



const pathjoin = path.join( __dirname ,'../public');





app.use(express.static(pathjoin));



MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/DETAILS',(err,client)=>{

 if(err){

  return console.log('unable to connect to the MongoDb server');

   }

  const db =client.db('DETAILS');



   console.log('connected to the MongoDb server');

 });



 io.on('connection',(socket)=>{

 console.log('new user connected');







//login

socket.on('login-details',(data)=>{

db.collection('user-
details').find({username:data.username,password:data.password},
(err,result)=>{

    if(err) throw err;

    socket.emit('login-response',{

        success:true

    });

 });

});

//signup

socket.on('signup-details',(data)=>{

db.collection('user-
details').insert({username:data.newuser,password:data.newuserpassword},
(err,result)=>{

    if(err) throw err;

    socket.emit('signup-response',{

        success:true

    });

  });

 });

});





 app.listen(port,()=>{

console.log('server started');

});
```

Comment: Show us exact errors texts.

Comment: GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js net::ERR_ABORTED
index.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined
    at index.js:1
(anonymous) @ index.js:1
localhost/:36 GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js net::ERR_ABORTED

Comment: Not in the comments, add to the post.

Comment: it is mentioned

Answer (score 4):

In your **server/server.js**, at the very end of your codes, change `app.listen()` to `server.listen()`, because express requires that you instantiate a **HTTP** server in Socket.IO.

This should be your new ending part of **server.js**

```
 server.listen(port,()=>{

console.log('server started');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

In index.html

`<script src = "index.js"></script>
 <script src = "/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`

change it to

```
        <script src = "/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src = "index.js"></script>
```

Swap the includes in html .First you need to include socket.io and then use it in index.js.

In index.js

```
var socket = io.connect();
```

Answer (score 1):

error solved. It was a silly mistake! since socket.io uses **http** server and not the express server. so i did create a **http** server but at during listening to a port i use express like `app.listen()`. In server/server.js it should be:

```
server.listen(port,()=>{ console.log('server started');});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this. Change,

```
<script src = "/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="http://YOUR_IP_ADDRESS/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Comment: Of course, add the port number after the ip address

Comment: i did the same thing. localhost:3000.. it doesnt work anyway!

Comment: that wont solve. .the error says it is unable to load client side socket.io hence io is not recognised!

Comment: i used the same logic to create the chat app ,it worked then but now it is showing error which makes me pull my hair

Comment: How's the server? What does it say after running? Are running it in fork mode?

Comment: Since socket.io is installed in your server. There should be server logs causing socket.io to behave improperly

Comment: the server is running on the given port . the error is shown in the console

Comment: yes. .but what is the reason behind socket to behave improperly?

Comment: You might have changes on your server code relating to socket.io. I remember I have encountered this before and it's on the server. Really

Comment: GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js net::ERR_ABORTED 
index.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined
    at index.js:1
(anonymous) @ index.js:1

Comment: As what I have encountered before, this error means that socket.io did not run properly on the server having io() undefined on the client